# Работа с COM-объектами .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, com

Пытаюсь использовать функцию GetApplicationVolume из примера https://gist.github.com/sverrirs/d099b34b7f72bb4fb386 вот так:

```
public static float? GetApplicationVolume(int pid)
{
    ISimpleAudioVolume volume = GetVolumeObject(pid);
    if (volume == null)
        return null;

    float level;
    volume.GetMasterVolume(out level);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(volume);
    return level * 100;
}

private static ISimpleAudioVolume GetVolumeObject(int pid)
{
    IMMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnumerator = null;
    IAudioSessionEnumerator sessionEnumerator = null;
    IAudioSessionManager2 mgr = null;
    IMMDevice speakers = null;
    try
    {
        // get the speakers (1st render + multimedia) device
        deviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)(new MMDeviceEnumerator());
        deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia, out speakers);

        // activate the session manager. we need the enumerator
        Guid IID_IAudioSessionManager2 = typeof(IAudioSessionManager2).GUID;
        object o;
        speakers.Activate(ref IID_IAudioSessionManager2, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out o);
        mgr = (IAudioSessionManager2)o;

        // enumerate sessions for on this device
        mgr.GetSessionEnumerator(out sessionEnumerator);
        int count;
        sessionEnumerator.GetCount(out count);

        // search for an audio session with the required process-id
        ISimpleAudioVolume volumeControl = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            IAudioSessionControl2 ctl = null;
            try
            {
                sessionEnumerator.GetSession(i, out ctl);

                // NOTE: we could also use the app name from ctl.GetDisplayName()
                int cpid;
                ctl.GetProcessId(out cpid);

                if (cpid == pid)
                {
                    volumeControl = ctl as ISimpleAudioVolume;
                    break;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (ctl != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl);
            }
        }

        return volumeControl;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sessionEnumerator != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sessionEnumerator);
        if (mgr != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mgr);
        if (speakers != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(speakers);
        if (deviceEnumerator != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(deviceEnumerator);
    }
}
```

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(AudioManager.GetApplicationVolume(5992).ToString());
    }
}
```

и получаю "Необработанное исключение: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException: Объект COM, который был отделен от своего базового RCW, использоваться не может.`

При гуглении залез в какие дебри про потоки и совсем запутался. Помогите! C C# и .NET до этого не работал, так что не кидайтесь тапками)

Comment: вот тут возьмите: https://gist.github.com/sverrirs/d099b34b7f72bb4fb386

Comment: Так это ж тоже самое))

Comment: я нашел баг в этом Gist, но вы не показали метод `GetVolumeObject`, в нем ошибка. Если добавите его код в вопрос, покажу как исправить.

Comment: Код метода добавил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот смотрите, в C# есть `IDisposable` объекты. Смысл этого интерфейса в том чтобы помочь разработчику правильно очищать неуправляемые ресурсы даже при возникновении исключений в управляемом коде. Либо отдать контроль своими неуправляемыми ресурсами сборщику мусора, но это уже другая история про финализаторы.

Для того, чтобы гарантированно вызвать какой-то код даже при возникновении исключения, используется конструкция `try-finally` или конкретно для `IDisposable` есть ее упрощенный синтаксис `using`. Почитать больше можно здесь: [Использование объектов, реализующих IDisposable](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects).

Так к чему я всё это. COM-объекты, это по сути вызов неуправляемого кода, например написанного на C++, но сделанного так, чтобы с ним можно было взаимодействовать через специальное API операционной системы под названием COM (Component Object Model). Так вот, если у реализующего `IDisposable` класса надо обязательно вызывать `Dispose()`, то у COM-объекта надо обязательно вызывать `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`, при чём используя ту же самую конструкцию `try-finally`, чтобы не быть причиной утечек памяти в случае, если возниколо исключение в управляемом коде и выполнение кода дальше не пошло.

```
try
{
    var obj = getComCobject();
    // работаем с COM-объектом
}
finally
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
}
```

И разработчик этого класса `AudioManager` очень строго следует этим принципам, и он перестарался.

Дело в том, что строки кода в методе `GetVolumeObject` выполняются (при попадании в нужный PID) в следующем порядке

```cs
// найден нужный COM-объект
if (cpid == pid) // true
{
    volumeControl = ctl as ISimpleAudioVolume;
    break;
}

// возврат результата
return volumeControl;

// и следом срабатывает
finally
{
    if (ctl != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl);
}
```

И при возврате в метод, вы пытаетесь обратиться к COM-объекту, для которого получается, что ранее уже был вызван `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`.

```cs
volume.GetMasterVolume(out float level);
```

Говоря дотнетовским языком, пытаетесь воспользоваться уже ранее уничтоженным объектом.

Что же делать? Самый простой способ - обмануть конструкцию блоке `finally`

```cs
finally
{
    if (ctl != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl);
}
```

Вот так

```
if (cpid == pid)
{
    volumeControl = ctl as ISimpleAudioVolume;
    ctl = null; // эту строчку нужно добавить в класс
    break;
}
```

В этом случае `volumeControl` вернется из метода `GetVolumeObject` в метод `GetApplicationVolume` в рабочем состоянии.

Я проверил подставив PID одного из своих процессов, для наглядности уменьшил немного громкость приложению, с которого её считывал.

```cs
Console.WriteLine(AudioManager.GetApplicationVolume(24240) ?? 0);
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
93,61702
```

Ну и вот это тоже работает

```cs
Console.WriteLine(AudioManager.GetMasterVolume());
```

```
47
```

---

Для будущих посетителей вставлю исправленный код целиком

**Структуры данных**

```cs
[ComImport]
[Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E")]
internal class MMDeviceEnumerator
{
}

internal enum EDataFlow
{
    eRender,
    eCapture,
    eAll,
    EDataFlow_enum_count
}

internal enum ERole
{
    eConsole,
    eMultimedia,
    eCommunications,
    ERole_enum_count
}

[Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IMMDeviceEnumerator
{
    int NotImpl1();

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow dataFlow, ERole role, out IMMDevice ppDevice);

    // the rest is not implemented
}

[Guid("D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IMMDevice
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int Activate(ref Guid iid, int dwClsCtx, IntPtr pActivationParams, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppInterface);

    // the rest is not implemented
}

[Guid("77AA99A0-1BD6-484F-8BC7-2C654C9A9B6F"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IAudioSessionManager2
{
    int NotImpl1();
    int NotImpl2();

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetSessionEnumerator(out IAudioSessionEnumerator SessionEnum);

    // the rest is not implemented
}

[Guid("E2F5BB11-0570-40CA-ACDD-3AA01277DEE8"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IAudioSessionEnumerator
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetCount(out int SessionCount);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetSession(int SessionCount, out IAudioSessionControl2 Session);
}

[Guid("87CE5498-68D6-44E5-9215-6DA47EF883D8"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface ISimpleAudioVolume
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetMasterVolume(float fLevel, ref Guid EventContext);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetMasterVolume(out float pfLevel);

    [PreserveSig]
    int SetMute(bool bMute, ref Guid EventContext);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetMute(out bool pbMute);
}

[Guid("bfb7ff88-7239-4fc9-8fa2-07c950be9c6d"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IAudioSessionControl2
{
    // IAudioSessionControl
    [PreserveSig]
    int NotImpl0();

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetDisplayName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string pRetVal);

    [PreserveSig]
    int SetDisplayName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Value, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid EventContext);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetIconPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string pRetVal);

    [PreserveSig]
    int SetIconPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Value, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid EventContext);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetGroupingParam(out Guid pRetVal);

    [PreserveSig]
    int SetGroupingParam([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid Override, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid EventContext);

    [PreserveSig]
    int NotImpl1();

    [PreserveSig]
    int NotImpl2();

    // IAudioSessionControl2
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetSessionIdentifier([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string pRetVal);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetSessionInstanceIdentifier([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string pRetVal);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetProcessId(out int pRetVal);

    [PreserveSig]
    int IsSystemSoundsSession();

    [PreserveSig]
    int SetDuckingPreference(bool optOut);
}

// http://netcoreaudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Code/CoreAudio/Interfaces/IAudioEndpointVolume.cs
[Guid("5CDF2C82-841E-4546-9722-0CF74078229A"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IAudioEndpointVolume
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int NotImpl1();

    [PreserveSig]
    int NotImpl2();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a count of the channels in the audio stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="channelCount">The number of channels.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetChannelCount(
        [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out uint channelCount);

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the master volume level of the audio stream, in decibels.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="level">The new master volume level in decibels.</param>
    /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetMasterVolumeLevel(
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] float level,
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid eventContext);

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the master volume level, expressed as a normalized, audio-tapered value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="level">The new master volume level expressed as a normalized value between 0.0 and 1.0.</param>
    /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] float level,
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid eventContext);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the master volume level of the audio stream, in decibels.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="level">The volume level in decibels.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetMasterVolumeLevel(
        [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] out float level);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the master volume level, expressed as a normalized, audio-tapered value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="level">The volume level expressed as a normalized value between 0.0 and 1.0.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(
        [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] out float level);

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the volume level, in decibels, of the specified channel of the audio stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="channelNumber">The channel number.</param>
    /// <param name="level">The new volume level in decibels.</param>
    /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetChannelVolumeLevel(
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint channelNumber,
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] float level,
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid eventContext);

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the normalized, audio-tapered volume level of the specified channel in the audio stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="channelNumber">The channel number.</param>
    /// <param name="level">The new master volume level expressed as a normalized value between 0.0 and 1.0.</param>
    /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint channelNumber,
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] float level,
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid eventContext);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the volume level, in decibels, of the specified channel in the audio stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="channelNumber">The zero-based channel number.</param>
    /// <param name="level">The volume level in decibels.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetChannelVolumeLevel(
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint channelNumber,
        [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] out float level);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the normalized, audio-tapered volume level of the specified channel of the audio stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="channelNumber">The zero-based channel number.</param>
    /// <param name="level">The volume level expressed as a normalized value between 0.0 and 1.0.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint channelNumber,
        [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] out float level);

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the muting state of the audio stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="isMuted">True to mute the stream, or false to unmute the stream.</param>
    /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetMute(
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool isMuted,
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid eventContext);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the muting state of the audio stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="isMuted">The muting state. True if the stream is muted, false otherwise.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetMute(
        [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] out bool isMuted);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets information about the current step in the volume range.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="step">The current zero-based step index.</param>
    /// <param name="stepCount">The total number of steps in the volume range.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetVolumeStepInfo(
        [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out uint step,
        [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out uint stepCount);

    /// <summary>
    /// Increases the volume level by one step.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int VolumeStepUp(
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid eventContext);

    /// <summary>
    /// Decreases the volume level by one step.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int VolumeStepDown(
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid eventContext);

    /// <summary>
    /// Queries the audio endpoint device for its hardware-supported functions.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hardwareSupportMask">A hardware support mask that indicates the capabilities of the endpoint.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int QueryHardwareSupport(
        [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out uint hardwareSupportMask);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the volume range of the audio stream, in decibels.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="volumeMin">The minimum volume level in decibels.</param>
    /// <param name="volumeMax">The maximum volume level in decibels.</param>
    /// <param name="volumeStep">The volume increment level in decibels.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetVolumeRange(
        [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] out float volumeMin,
        [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] out float volumeMax,
        [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] out float volumeStep);
}
```

**AudioManager.cs**

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Controls audio using the Windows CoreAudio API
/// from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306048/controling-volume-mixer
/// and: http://netcoreaudio.codeplex.com/
/// </summary>
public static class AudioManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current master volume in scalar values (percentage)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>-1 in case of an error, if successful the value will be between 0 and 100</returns>
    public static float GetMasterVolume()
    {
        IAudioEndpointVolume masterVol = null;
        try
        {
            masterVol = GetMasterVolumeObject();
            if (masterVol == null)
                return -1;

            masterVol.GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(out float volumeLevel);
            return volumeLevel * 100;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (masterVol != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(masterVol);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the mute state of the master volume. 
    /// While the volume can be muted the <see cref="GetMasterVolume"/> will still return the pre-muted volume value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>false if not muted, true if volume is muted</returns>
    public static bool GetMasterVolumeMute()
    {
        IAudioEndpointVolume masterVol = null;
        try
        {
            masterVol = GetMasterVolumeObject();
            if (masterVol == null)
                return false;

            masterVol.GetMute(out bool isMuted);
            return isMuted;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (masterVol != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(masterVol);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the master volume to a specific level
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newLevel">Value between 0 and 100 indicating the desired scalar value of the volume</param>
    public static void SetMasterVolume(float newLevel)
    {
        IAudioEndpointVolume masterVol = null;
        try
        {
            masterVol = GetMasterVolumeObject();
            if (masterVol == null)
                return;

            masterVol.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(newLevel / 100, Guid.Empty);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (masterVol != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(masterVol);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Increments or decrements the current volume level by the <see cref="stepAmount"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stepAmount">Value between -100 and 100 indicating the desired step amount. Use negative numbers to decrease
    /// the volume and positive numbers to increase it.</param>
    /// <returns>the new volume level assigned</returns>
    public static float StepMasterVolume(float stepAmount)
    {
        IAudioEndpointVolume masterVol = null;
        try
        {
            masterVol = GetMasterVolumeObject();
            if (masterVol == null)
                return -1;

            float stepAmountScaled = stepAmount / 100;

            // Get the level
            masterVol.GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(out float volumeLevel);

            // Calculate the new level
            float newLevel = volumeLevel + stepAmountScaled;
            newLevel = Math.Min(1, newLevel);
            newLevel = Math.Max(0, newLevel);

            masterVol.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(newLevel, Guid.Empty);

            // Return the new volume level that was set
            return newLevel * 100;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (masterVol != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(masterVol);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mute or unmute the master volume
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="isMuted">true to mute the master volume, false to unmute</param>
    public static void SetMasterVolumeMute(bool isMuted)
    {
        IAudioEndpointVolume masterVol = null;
        try
        {
            masterVol = GetMasterVolumeObject();
            if (masterVol == null)
                return;

            masterVol.SetMute(isMuted, Guid.Empty);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (masterVol != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(masterVol);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Switches between the master volume mute states depending on the current state
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>the current mute state, true if the volume was muted, false if unmuted</returns>
    public static bool ToggleMasterVolumeMute()
    {
        IAudioEndpointVolume masterVol = null;
        try
        {
            masterVol = GetMasterVolumeObject();
            if (masterVol == null)
                return false;

            masterVol.GetMute(out bool isMuted);
            masterVol.SetMute(!isMuted, Guid.Empty);

            return !isMuted;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (masterVol != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(masterVol);
        }
    }

    private static IAudioEndpointVolume GetMasterVolumeObject()
    {
        IMMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnumerator = null;
        IMMDevice speakers = null;
        try
        {
            deviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)new MMDeviceEnumerator();
            deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia, out speakers);

            Guid IID_IAudioEndpointVolume = typeof(IAudioEndpointVolume).GUID;
            speakers.Activate(ref IID_IAudioEndpointVolume, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out object o);
            IAudioEndpointVolume masterVol = (IAudioEndpointVolume)o;

            return masterVol;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (speakers != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(speakers);
            if (deviceEnumerator != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(deviceEnumerator);
        }
    }

    public static float? GetApplicationVolume(int pid)
    {
        ISimpleAudioVolume volume = GetVolumeObject(pid);
        if (volume == null)
            return null;

        volume.GetMasterVolume(out float level);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(volume);
        return level * 100;
    }

    public static bool? GetApplicationMute(int pid)
    {
        ISimpleAudioVolume volume = GetVolumeObject(pid);
        if (volume == null)
            return null;

        volume.GetMute(out bool mute);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(volume);
        return mute;
    }

    public static void SetApplicationVolume(int pid, float level)
    {
        ISimpleAudioVolume volume = GetVolumeObject(pid);
        if (volume == null)
            return;

        Guid guid = Guid.Empty;
        volume.SetMasterVolume(level / 100, ref guid);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(volume);
    }

    public static void SetApplicationMute(int pid, bool mute)
    {
        ISimpleAudioVolume volume = GetVolumeObject(pid);
        if (volume == null)
            return;

        Guid guid = Guid.Empty;
        volume.SetMute(mute, ref guid);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(volume);
    }

    private static ISimpleAudioVolume GetVolumeObject(int pid)
    {
        IMMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnumerator = null;
        IAudioSessionEnumerator sessionEnumerator = null;
        IAudioSessionManager2 mgr = null;
        IMMDevice speakers = null;
        try
        {
            // get the speakers (1st render + multimedia) device
            deviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)new MMDeviceEnumerator();
            deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia, out speakers);

            // activate the session manager. we need the enumerator
            Guid IID_IAudioSessionManager2 = typeof(IAudioSessionManager2).GUID;
            speakers.Activate(ref IID_IAudioSessionManager2, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out object o);
            mgr = (IAudioSessionManager2)o;

            // enumerate sessions for on this device
            mgr.GetSessionEnumerator(out sessionEnumerator);
            sessionEnumerator.GetCount(out int count);

            // search for an audio session with the required process-id
            ISimpleAudioVolume volumeControl = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                IAudioSessionControl2 ctl = null;
                try
                {
                    sessionEnumerator.GetSession(i, out ctl);

                    // NOTE: we could also use the app name from ctl.GetDisplayName()
                    ctl.GetProcessId(out int cpid);

                    if (cpid == pid)
                    {
                        volumeControl = ctl as ISimpleAudioVolume;
                        ctl = null;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (ctl != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl);
                }
            }

            return volumeControl;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sessionEnumerator != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sessionEnumerator);
            if (mgr != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mgr);
            if (speakers != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(speakers);
            if (deviceEnumerator != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(deviceEnumerator);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь и такой подробный ответ!