# Как увеличить громкость в приложение как в Windows?

Tags: c#, winforms, аудио

Используя данный код:

```
    [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public static extern uint waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr hwo, out uint dwVolume);

    [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public static extern uint waveOutSetVolume(int uDeviceID, uint dwVolume);

    [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public static extern uint waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr uDeviceID, uint dwVolume);

    [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "waveOutSetVolume")]
    public static extern int WaveOutSetVolume(IntPtr hwo, uint dwVolume);

    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    public static extern int waveOutSetVolume(int wDeviceID, int dwVolume);

    [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool PlaySound(string pszSound, IntPtr hmod, uint fdwSound);

    public static void SetSoundVolume(int volume)
    {
        try
        {
            //int currVol = (int)(50 * 0xFFFF / (double)100);
            //currVol += currVol << 16;
            //waveOutSetVolume(0, currVol);

            int newVolume = ushort.MaxValue / 10 * volume;
            uint newVolumeAllChannels = ((uint)newVolume & 0x0000ffff) | ((uint)newVolume << 16);
            //waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, out newVolumeAllChannels);
            waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, newVolumeAllChannels);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    public static int GetSoundVolume()
    {
        int value = 0;
        try
        {
            waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, out uint curVolume);
            ushort CalcVol = (ushort)(curVolume & 0x0000ffff);
            value = CalcVol / (ushort.MaxValue /10);
        }
        catch { }
        return value;
    }
```

Как мне в моём приложение сделать громкость на половину?
Хотелось бы чтобы можно было изменять от 0 до 100 - это максимум.

Comment: waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, 0x7FFF7FFF).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1354178/373567 вдруг пригодится

Comment: @aepot, это вообще чудо из чудес) Но метод: `AudioManager.SetApplicationVolume` кажется работает как-то не так или вообще не работает. Попробовал изменить так: `AudioManager.SetApplicationVolume(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, 10f);` но громкость так и осталась в приложение.

Comment: Это может означать, что для данного приложения операционная система не выделила аудио подсистему, то есть не считает его воспроизводящим звук. В том ответе я регулировал громкость для браузера FireFox, а не для моего приложения. То есть если вы откроете миксер, можете увидеть регуляторы громкости для запущенных приложений, воспроизводящих звук, именно этими регуляторами `AudioManager` и управляет. Если в списке регуляторов вашего приложения нет, то и управлять соответственно нечем.

Comment: `float? volume = AudioManager.GetApplicationVolume(pid);`, если вернуло `null`, значит нет регулятора громкости для этого `pid`.